# Postgresql - ORDER BY random() but also sort by id?

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, sql-order-by

is it possible to order by random, and then order by an id?

In other words - can I tell to postgresql that it should return 10 random elements, but also give it out by sorting by the id column?

Right now it seems I can do
ORDER BY random()
and that works, but I get a wild, unsorted result, so I now want to sort that result by the main id it uses, but I seem to be unable to apply to ORDER BY statements.

Normally I would sort by doing this:

ORDER BY id

But this does not work if I already order by random...

Answer (score 4):

Maybe like this?

```
select * from
  (select * from ...
    order by random()
    limit 10
  )
order by id
```

Comment: Yep, use an inner subquery with limit to select the rows, then an outer query to sort the result.